# Android vertical RecyclerView's height inside ConstraintLayout becomes 0;

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, androidx

In the android studio's preview the app is fine but in runtime the height becomes zero; Here is the xml of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/filemaneger_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f6f6f6"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

by the way the app works fine in relative layout;

Comment: i believe you are adding the data also inside the recyclerview

Comment: It should be worked, Check your data list that you want to populate inside RecyclerView

Comment: what i guess is you are using dialogFragment.please note if i right

Comment: @shadow no but im using androidx Fragment;

Comment: whats with the downvoting? this is an actual problem!

Comment: @shadow can you please elaborate on the DialogFragment thing. it might be the same issue since im using androidx Fragment;

Comment: oh,sorry i miss your comment.@kamyarhaqqani.no i think not,cause i only caught that when i use dialog fragment.My issue is if you not define the height,or min height,or the height of the dialog framgent,it will calculate the recyclerview = 0 no matter how you anchor the view

Comment: better you try to use layout inspector to see how your recycler view is display from that time.on toolbar, select tools -> layout inspector

Comment: @Shadow thanks. I think it reflexes a bug in either constraintlayout or recyclerview given that height and width of 0dp works fine in other layouts. I should bug report it.

Comment: @kamyarhaqqani im not sure about it,but my layout always work fine if using the same as your